# Having problems with ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

So when trying to retrieve my balance via the MtGox Ruby gem, here is what happens:

```
MtGox.configure do |config|
  config.key = "XXXXX"
  config.secret = "XXXXXXX"
end

puts MtGox.balance
```

That code returns the object's memory placement:

```
#< MtGox::Balance:0xXXXXX >
#< MtGox::Balance:0xXXXXXX >
```

How can I fix that?

When I put `MtGox.balance.to_s` :

```
[#< MtGox::Balance:0x00xxxxxxxx @currency="BTC", @amount=1>, #< MtGox::Balance:0xxxxxx @currency="USD", @amount=1>]
```

Comment: `MtGox.balance.amount`?

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW is right. MtGox.balance returns an object with attributes currency and amount. https://github.com/sferik/mtgox/blob/master/lib/mtgox/balance.rb

Comment: what methods does MtGox.balance present?

Answer (score 1):

check out the [MtGox API Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mtgox/0.9.0/frames)

try

```
 MtGox.balance.amount

 MtGox.balance.currency
```